# Understanding uWSGI in the context of PHP

Tags: java, php, django, wsgi, application-server

I have worked mostly with PHP and to some extent with Java. And currently looking at Python and Django. When a Django project is deployed on production, it is required to choose one of servers that implement `wsgi` specification.

The definition is pretty straight forward as well as history. Looking back at php world I don't see a parallel with `wsgi` and that creates some confusion and probably an opportunity to learn more about it.

So the questions is what makes python application special that they require (frameworks as well as servers) to implement `wsgi` specification ?

Do we have similar specification for php ? any reasons for having/having not ? Probably a unique issue with python ? however, I see we can use uWSGI with php applications also.

Is `wsgi` is something similar to `Java Servlet` specification ? and uWSGI server is like `Tomcat` i.e `Application Server`.

If we consider a `wsgi` server as `Application Server`, what services it does provide e.g  manage security, transaction processing, resource pooling, and messaging or more/all of them ?

Comment: The parallel with a wsgi server is mod_php; you can't run PHP on pure Apache, you need something that interprets the PHP and runs the script. It's not exactly the same thing because mod_php embeds the intepreter in Apache, but it's the same underlying idea; WSGI is the interface between the web server and Python.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I understand that, I am looking at uWSGI in the context of other languages. Does mod_php implement a standard like `wsgi` ? Why python based framework need a standard like `wsgi`? I need a comparative outlook on this standard